# Using closure with a promise in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures, angular-promise

I don't have a lot of experience with `JavaScript closures` nor `AngularJS promises`. So, here is my scenario

**Goal**:

I need to make `$http` requests calls within a `for` loop

**(Obvious) problem**

Even though the loop is done, my variables still have not been updated

**Current implementation**

```
function getColumns(fieldParameters)
{
    return $http.get("api/fields", { params: fieldParameters });
}

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.model.Fields.length; i++)
{
    var current = $scope.model.Fields[i];

    (function(current){
        fieldParameters.uid = $scope.model.Uid;
        fieldParameters.type = "Columns";
        fieldParameters.tableId = current.Value.Uid;                    
        var promise = getColumns(fieldParameters);                  
        promise.then(function(response){
           current.Value.Columns = response.data;
        }, error); 
    })(current);                                                                     
}

//at this point current.Value.Columns should be filled with the response. However
//it's still empty
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a list of fields that you need to do some work on.  Then when all of that async work is done, you want to continue.  So using the $q.all() should do the trick.  It will resolve when all of the list of promises handed to it resolve.  So it's essentially like "wait until all of this stuff finishes, then do this"

You could try something like this:

```
var promises = [];

for(var i=0; i< $scope.model.Fields.length; i++) {
  var current = $scope.model.Fields[i];
  promises.push(getColumns(fieldParameters).then(function(response) {
    current.Value.Columns = response.data;
  }));
}

return $q.all(promises).then(function() {
  // This is when all of your promises are completed.
  // So check your $scope.model.Fields here. 
});
```

EDIT:

Try this since you are not seeing the right item updated.  Update your getColumns method to accept the field, the send the field in the getColumns call:

```
function getColumns(fieldParameters, field)
{
    return $http.get("api/fields", { params: fieldParameters}).then(function(response) {
field.Value.Columns = response.data;
    });
}


...

promises.push(getColumns(fieldParameters, $scope.model.Fields[i])...
```

Comment: It works however the data is not been updated to the right `current` object. That's why I think I need a closure here. I'm going to upvote you anyway for the partial answer.

Comment: @LuisLavieri See my edit above.  I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. That was very close. I had to pass freaking `i` and populate the `fieldParameter` object inside the `$http` to make it work at the end

Comment: The important thing @LuisLavieri is that you believed in yourself.  Never give up.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
  var promises = [];      

  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.model.Fields.length; i++)
  {
     var current = $scope.model.Fields[i];
     promises.push(function(current){
         //blahblah 
         return promise
     });
  }


  $q.all(promises).then(function(){
      /// everything has finished all variables updated
  });
```

Comment: It works however the data is not been updated to the right `current` object. That's why I think I need the closure here. However, I am still going to upvote you for the partial answer. Thanks